# Calcular el valor promedio de un carrito de la compra en Python

Tags: python

Buenas tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:
Escriba una función llamada get_average_item_price que tome el carrito de compras como entrada y devuelva el promedio de todos los precios de los artículos.
Sugerencia: esto debería determinar el precio total dividido por la cantidad de tipos de artículos. Esto no tiene en cuenta la cantidad de cada tipo de artículo.

Nos dan esto:

```
shopping_cart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "beans",
            "price": 0.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "chili sauce",
            "price": 2.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "chocolate",
            "price": 0.75,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

Y yo he hecho esto:

```
def get_average_item_price(shopping_cart):
    total_spent = 0
    quantity_of_items = 0
    for item in shopping_cart:
        total_spent += item["price"]
        quantity_of_items += item["quantity"]

    average_per_item = total_spent / quantity_of_items
    return average_per_item
    
    assert get_average_item_price(shopping_cart) == 2.1420000000000003
    print("Exercise 99 is complete.")
```

Y esto es el error que me esta dando:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_36/876830592.py in <module>
     14     return average_per_item
     15 
---> 16 assert get_average_item_price(shopping_cart) == 2.1420000000000003
     17 print("Exercise 99 is complete.")

/tmp/ipykernel_36/876830592.py in get_average_item_price(shopping_cart)
      8     quantity_of_items = 0
      9     for item in shopping_cart:
---> 10         total_spent += item["price"]
     11         quantity_of_items += item["quantity"]
     12 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Espero me ayuden a resolver la duda y muchas gracias

Comment: ADVERTENCIA: No se deben comparar 2 numeros flotantes directamente. Esto porque internamente los datos se representan de forma aproximada. Supongamos que `a = 8/2` y `b = 12/3`, es posible que internamente se representen como: `a = 4.000001` y `b = 3.999999`. [Leer más al respecto](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+why+not+compare+two+floats)

Answer (score 2):

#### Explicación

Creo que no analisaste correctamente la estructura del diccionario (sin intención de ofender).

shopping_cart es un diccionario, NO una lista. Si intentas iterar en un diccionario, obtendrás cada clave del diccionario, es decir, el equivalente a hacer `for item in ("tax", "items")` en este caso particular.

Y como item es una cadena, no un diccionario, al intentar acceder a lo que vos crees que es un valor de un diccionario ocurre un error. Es decir, es el equivalente a hacer `"tax"["price"]` por ejemplo.

#### Solución

Primero hay que entender la estructura de shopping_cart. Dentro de dicho diccionario hay dos items:

- `"tax"` que es un numero flotante
- `"items"` que es una lista de diccionarios.

En conclusión, para obtener cada item habría que iterar sobre `shopping_cart["items"]`, no `shopping_cart`.

Por lo tanto, la solución es tan simple como cambiar esta linea:

```
for item in shopping_cart:
```

Por esta:

```
for item in shopping_cart["items"]:
```

Lo demás que hiciste está perfecto c:

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta compareño lo he hecho como me has comentado y me sale el siguiente error: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_37/419253723.py in <module>
     14     return average_per_item
     15 
---> 16 assert get_average_item_price(shopping_cart) == 2.1420000000000003
     17 print("Exercise 99 is complete.")

AssertionError: `

Comment: De nada! @samuel eso sucede por que el resultado de tu función no es igual a 2.1420000000000003. El assert que está en tu código hace que ocurra un error si la igualdad  `get_average_item_price(shopping_cart) == 2.1420000000000003` no se cumple. Revisa si lo que devuelve tu función es igual a 2.1420000000000003. O quita el assert.

Comment: Pues debería dar ese resultado, no se como verificarlo de otra forma ya que soy principiante. Y uso Kaggle para programas

Comment: La pregunta para @Samuel es: Por qué tienes que compararlo con ese valor exactamente? De dónde sale?

Comment: @Alfabravo es la comprobación que viene dada en el ejercicio puesta por el profesor, yo comprobé con una calculadora si debía dar ese resultado y si es correcto. Pero no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: @Samuel Por favor, edita tu pregunta e indica allí cuál es la comprobación que hiciste con la calculadora. Si uno toma cada precio, lo suma y divide entre el número de productos diferentes que hay (5), da 2,142. Sin más cifras significativas.

Answer (score -1):

Compañeros ya esta resuelta la duda y el ejercicio, segun el enunciado no habia que tener en cuenta la cantidad de cada articulo por lo tanto era sustituir esta linea de codigo:

```
quantity_of_items += item["quantity"]
```

por:

```
quantity_of_items = len(shopping_cart["items"])
```

Un saludo y gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: quantity_of_items siempre va a valer 5. Estás obteniendo la cantidad de letras que tiene la palabra "items". Por pura casualidad la cantidad de items real coincide con la cantidad de letras de la palabra "items". Aparte, donde haces ese cambio? Si lo haces dentro del  bucle for estás reasignando el mismo valor una y otra vez a la misma variable, y eso es innecesario.

Comment: Si quieres puedo orientarte a obtener el numero de forma correcta. Si estás de acuerdo dime en los comentarios!

Comment: Muchas gracias @DanteS. pero ya lo he solucionado. Un saludo

Comment: de nada! Pero te estoy advirtiendo de un error logico en el cambio que hiciste para solucionarlo, que funcione con un caso no significa que funcione para todos. Si shopping_cart["items"] tubiera 6 items en lugar de 5, la solución propuesta en tu respuesta no funcionaria correctamente. Cambiaste ese `quantity_of_items = len("items")` por otra cosa?

Comment: len("items"), no te da la cantidad de items que hay en el diccionario?

Comment: Nope, primero que nada, shopping_cart["items"] es una lista, no un diccionario. Segundo, lee el primer comentario que dejé en tu respuesta, ahí lo aclaro. len("items") obtiene la cantidad de letras de la palabra "items".

Comment: Plantealo así, estás preguntandole a Python ¿Cual es el largo de "items"?

Comment: No, lo que quiero hacer es preguntar la cantidad de artículos distintos que hay en el carrito en este caso 5. Si me pudieras ayudar te lo agradecería. Un saludo

Comment: Dale! Te ayudo! Te acuerdas como acceder a la lista de items? Te lo dije en mi respuesta. Recuerda analizar la estructura.

Comment: shopping_cart es un diccionario, que hay en ese diccionario?

Comment: Hay una variable tax y una lista de items.  Y asi se accede a la lista de items no? shopping_cart["items"]

Comment: Exacto! Y como puedes obtener el largo de una lista?

Comment: Con la función len() no?

Comment: Muy bien! Entonces cual es la forma correcta de obtener la cantidad de items en la lista?

Comment: len(shopping_cart["items"])?

Comment: Eso mismo! Ahora te recomiendo editar tu respuesta y tu código aplicando esa linea de código a la que llegamos entre los dos c:

Comment: Miuchas gracias @DanteS. Un saludo

Comment: Es un placer ayudar nwn

Comment: `media = sum( x['price'] for x in shopping_cart['items'] ) / len(shopping_cart['items'])` Comprensión de listas, rápido y bonito